# Perl ActiveState - How to set Integer variable to 32-bit width on Windows x64?

Tags: perl

> $ perl -V | grep use64bitint
>    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef

I have installed ActiveState 5.20 for Perl 64 on Windows. Integer variables are allocated in memory as 64-bit. Is is possible to switch to 32-bit integer?

I tried to google and got this :

http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.18/lib/pods/perl5180delta.html#Incompatible-Changes

> "A new makefile option, USE_64_BIT_INT, has been added to the Windows makefiles. Set this to "define" when building a 32-bit perl if you want it to use 64-bit integers."

The issue is that I installed through *.msi so It did not prompt to enable/disable this option.

Comment: It can only be set when you build perl

Comment: your question and subject don't match.   If you want to force 32-bit math, it might help to explain why, as there may be a way to coerce your results into 32-bit numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simplest to install 32-bit ActivePerl instead?

Comment: There is nothing under *Incompatible Changes* about your problem. The text you quote is from *Platform-Specific Notes/Win32*, and it provides for 64-bit integers on a 32-bit build of Perl, not the other way around

Comment: @ikegami : the problem is that I didn't find any ways to enable/disable this option when installing ActivePerl on Windows. Could you please help to give instruction more details ?

Comment: You said you installed from msi, but it has to be set when perl is built.

Comment: Why do you want 32-bit integers?

Comment: @SinanÜnür : this can reduce size of my script when I create executable file.

Comment: @ChuongVo I am not sure if I understand your claim. In any case, you need to [compile your own `perl`](http://www.nu42.com/2014/11/64-bit-perl-5201-with-visual-studio.html). Edit `win32\Makefile` to disable 64 bit integers. Also, run the build from the 32-bit build environment. ActivePerl distribute what they distribute. If you want something else, you need to build your own.

Comment: @ChuongVo: How are you creating an executable file from your script?

Comment: @Borodin : I use PerlApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl guarantees that integers values are large enough to hold a pointer. As such, a 32-bit bit `perl`'s integers will be at least 32 bits in size, and a 64-bit bit `perl`'s integers will be at least 64 bits in size.

By default, a 32-bit `perl` will use 32-bit integers, but it's possible to pass flag `-Duse64bitint` to `Configure` to have the build process build a 32-bit `perl` that uses 64-bit integers instead. `Configure` isn't used on Windows build, but the same behaviour can be obtained by editing the value of `USE_64_BIT_INT` in the makefile.

You chose to download a pre-built `perl` from ActiveState rather than building your own. ActiveState now uses the equivalent of `-Duse64bitint` when building its 32-bit `perl`.

```
>perl -v | find "This is"
This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int

>perl -V:archname
archname='MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int';   # x86 = 32-bit binary
                                             # x64 = 64-bit binary
>perl -V:use64bitint
use64bitint='define';                        # -Duse64bitint or makefile equiv was used

>perl -V:ivsize                              # Size of integer values
ivsize='8';                                  # 8 bytes = 64 bits
```

If you want a build of Perl that uses 32-bit integers, you'll need to build your own or have someone else build one for you. (Strawberry Perl's 32-bit Perl might use 32-bit integers.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want 32-bit integers then install 32-bit ActivePerl. (Better still, install 32-bit Strawberry Perl)

The `USE_64_BIT_INT` option is for enabling 64-bit integers on a 32-bit Perl, which isn't what you're asking for

If you explain the problem that you're trying to solve by restricting your Perl installation to using 32-bit integers then I am sure we will be able to help better

Comment: The 32-bit ActivePerl uses 64-bit ints

Answer (score 0):

I write this answer based on your comment that you are using `PerlApp` and want a smaller .exe in the end.

PerlApp does not "compile" perl scripts in the conventional sense.  It wraps up a perl .dll with your script source, the source of any used/included modules and the .dll files of any XS modules and an extractor stub, all into a single self extracting/executing Zip archive.

As such, the size of your in-memory variables will have little relation to the size of the textual name of that variable in your script when it is encapsulated in the .exe

---

Possible actions that may affect the size of your resultant .exe:

- Tell PerlApp to use the "Windows" target instead of the "Windows 64" target to get a relatively minor savings of including 32 bit instead of 64 bit .dlls .
- Build your .exe with the `--dependent` or `--trim` options to remove some larger files from the archive entirely.  (Those files will have to be available on the system separately)

Now the caveat:  These options require that ActivePerl and/or Modules be installed on the target machine.  If your .exe is the only one in use, you will, in the end, gain nothing at the price of increasing your maintenance overhead.  If there are several PerlApp generated .exe files on the machine, the space savings of not including the perl .dll in each of them can be significant.

---

One final word:  I find PerlApp a helpful way of delivering a Perl program in a single self-contained file.  The same could be accomplished with any decent installation wizard.  The overhead of the PerlApp packaging process is generally a poor way to reduce required disk space, memory usage, or even start-up time.  It is also a remarkably poor protection from reverse engineering, even though it is frequently used for this purpose.

Comment: I am not sure I can built my.exe file with `--dependent` or `--trim` option because this exe file will run on  target machine that might not have same modules as my machine. I am trying to recompile Perl myself with some modification in _win32/Makefile_

Comment: I expect PerlApp will fail miserably with a non-ActiveState build of Perl.  Without an ActivePerl build you may have better luck with `PAR::Packer` and one of the Strawberry Perl builds without USE_64_BIT_INT.  Check out the 3rd box (as of 2015-04-23) at http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html